# Replacing <title> content with <h1>

Tags: regex, shell, sed

Or more generally, how to replace a pattern with another captured pattern.

I want to do this for multiple html files. Like:

```
find . -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's/(?<=title\>).*(?=\<\/title)/string2/g'
```

except `string2` is dynamically captured with another pattern.

**UPDATE**

A little bit verbose though, but I mostly work it out via a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
h1=`grep -oP '(?<=h1\>)(?!FreeType).*(?=\<\/h1)' $file`  # I want to find a h1 tag without a 'FreeType' word in it
echo ${h1} finded
perl -i.bak -pe "s[(?<=title\>).*(?=\<\/title)][${h1}]g" $file
```

and

```
 find . -name '*.html' -exec ~/replace.sh {} \;
```

Comment: sed wont support lookbehind. You could use perl instead of sed.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I was wondering why can't I capture the content. And that's why.

Answer (score 1):

sed doesn't support look arounds, but you can just capture the tags and put them back:

```
find . -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's_<title>.*?</title>_<title>$string2</title>_g'
```

I changed the quantifier to *reluctant* to avoid matches gobbling up all the input from the first open tag to the last close tag as one match.

Also note how you can avoid saw tooth patterns (ie escaping slashes `\/\/`) by using a character other than `/` as the delimiter - here I used underscore, but you can use anything - to make the pattern more readable.

Comment: The key point of my questions is actually about how to replace the content of <title> tag with a captured content of <h1> tag instead of a static string 'string2'. Can I use group to capture the `<title>|<h1>` and replace it with say `$1` which is the <h1> group